# WooCommerce discount: buy one get one 50% off with a notice

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, discount

After my previous question *[WooCommerce discount: buy one get one 50% off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46264431/woocommerce-discount-buy-one-get-one-50-off)* I want to add custom notice to the cart, whenever a particular product(not all the products) gets added to the cart.

I want to check the quantity first, if it's 1 then I want to display a notice to increase the quantity of that product. I have figured something by myself from the internet and I don't think my solution is right:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'sp_custom_notice' );
function sp_custom_notice() {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;
    
    //to display notice only on cart page
    if ( ! is_cart() ) {
        return;
    }

    global $product;

    $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;
    if($product_id == 15730){
        //check for quantify if equal to 1 in cart


        wc_clear_notices();
        wc_add_notice( __("Add one more to get 50% off on 2nd product"), 'notice');
    }
}
```

It will be great if anyone can help me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** *July 2020*

If you are still using the code [from my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46264431/woocommerce-discount-buy-one-get-one-50-off) to your previous question, you can change it a bit to get this working too:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_custom_discount_2nd_at_50', 10, 1 );
function add_custom_discount_2nd_at_50( $cart ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) 
        return;

    // YOUR SETTINGS:
    $targeted_product_id = 40; // Set HERE your targeted product ID

    // Initializing variables
    $discount = $qty_notice = 0;
    $items_prices = array();

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $key => $cart_item ) {
        if( in_array( $targeted_product_id, [$cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item['variation_id']] ) ){
            $quantity = (int) $cart_item['quantity'];
            $qty_notice += $quantity;
            for( $i = 0; $i < $quantity; $i++ ) {
                $items_prices[] = floatval( $cart_item['data']->get_price());
            }
        }
    }

    $count_items = count($items_prices); // Count items

    rsort($items_prices); // Sorting prices descending order

    if( $count_items > 1 ) {
        foreach( $items_prices as $key => $price ) {
            if( $key % 2 == 1 )
                $discount -= number_format( $price / 2, 2 );
        }
    }

    // Applying the discount
    if( $discount != 0 ){
        $cart->add_fee('Buy one get one 50% off', $discount );

        // Displaying a custom notice (optional)
        wc_clear_notices(); // clear other notices on checkout page.
        if( ! is_checkout() ){
            wc_add_notice( __("You get 50% of discount on the 2nd item"), 'notice');
        }
    }
    //  Display a custom notice on cart page when quantity is equal to 1.
    elseif( $qty_notice == 1 ){
        wc_clear_notices(); // clear other notices on checkout page.
        if( ! is_checkout() ){
            wc_add_notice( __( "Add one more to get 50% off on 2nd item" ), 'notice');
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme)* Tested and works.

> **Note:** The **`wc_add_notice()`** function **absolutely don't need to be echoed**

Comment: thanks again for saving me, you are awesome...:) @loictheaztec

Comment: @LoicTheAztec: Hi Loic. What changes should I make to get this working in a different way. I'd like to apply a discount if any three variations of a product are in the cart. I want to take $7.5 off the total. I've got it triggering for 3 variations, but changing `$price / 2` to `$price - 7.5` did work as I thought it might. Should I post this in a new question?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec - I ended up creating a new question, as I realised it's too complex handling this in a comment. https://stackoverflow.com/q/63570504/1092677

Answer (score 0):

You did pretty good code some minor changes are required try below code :

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'sp_custom_notice');
function sp_custom_notice() {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    //to display notice only on cart page
    if ( ! is_cart() ) {
     return;
    }

   global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
        foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
            $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id()); 

            if($values['data']->get_id() == 190 && $values['quantity'] == 1 ){
                wc_clear_notices();
                echo wc_add_notice( __("Add one more to get 50% off on 2nd product"), 'notice');
            }
        } 
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I want to check the quantity first. @akshayshah

Comment: check now please

Comment: i am using a plugin named snippets, to place the code, mostly I use this plugin to place the code and it does work. But I donno why this code is not working.

Comment: No we need that