# WooCommerce - Buy one Get one Free

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, coupon

I have created a code in WooCommerce Coupon Codes called "2FOR1WOW" and added this code to functions.php but it's not working. The ticket gets applied and a confirmation message says it's ok but the total is not reduced.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
// Hook before calculate fees - "Buy 2 get cheapest free" coupon
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'buy2_coupon');

/**
 * Add discount for "Buy 2 get cheapest free" coupon
 * @param WC_Cart $cart
 */

function buy2_coupon( WC_Cart $cart ){

    // add the coupons here
    $buy2_coupons = array('2FOR1WOW', 'anothercouponcode');

    // return if cart has less than 2 items
    if( $cart->cart_contents_count < 2 ){
        return;
    }

    $applied_coupons = $cart->get_applied_coupons();    
    $matches = array_intersect($buy2_coupons, $applied_coupons);

    // return if no coupon matches
    if (empty($matches)) return;

    // loop through the items in cart to find the cheapest
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];
        $product_price[] = $_product->get_price_including_tax();
    }

    $cheapest = min($product_price);

    $cart->add_fee( 'Coupon 2FOR1WOW', -$cheapest, true, 'standard' );
}
```

Comment: isn't the question's title sounds a bit like marketing slogan of woocommerce product;

Answer (score 0):

Since WooCommerce 3+, the WC_Product `get_price_including_tax()` is deprecated and has been replaced by the function [**`wc_get_price_excluding_tax()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_price_excluding_tax.html#932-963) (not anymore a method).

You should **not need any coupon code** to make this kind of code working. As you are using them to fired this discount "Buy one Get one Free", I keep it on the function below.

What you have forgotten in your code is:

- to take care of quantities, when you are adding the product prices in your prices array.
- to get all necessary cheapest prices array, when there is multiple items, with different quantities.

The **`min()`** php function will work only on one item, so it's not really appropriated.

So the correct code should be something like:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'buy_one_get_one_free', 10, 1 );
function buy_one_get_one_free( $wc_cart ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    $cart_item_count = $wc_cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    if ( $cart_item_count < 2 ) return;

    // Set HERE your coupon codes
    $coupons_codes = array('2for1wow', 'anothercouponcode');
    $discount = 0; // initializing

    $matches = array_intersect( $coupons_codes, $wc_cart->get_applied_coupons() );
    if( count($matches) == 0 ) return;

    // Iterating through cart items
    foreach ( $wc_cart->get_cart() as $key => $cart_item ) {
        $qty = intval( $cart_item['quantity'] );
        // Iterating through item quantities
        for( $i = 0; $i < $qty; $i++ )
            $items_prices[] = floatval( wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $cart_item['data'] ) );
    }
    asort($items_prices); // Sorting cheapest prices first

    // Get the number of free items (detecting odd or even number of prices)
    if( $cart_item_count % 2 == 0 ) $free_item_count = $cart_item_count / 2;
    else  $free_item_count = ($cart_item_count - 1) / 2;

    // keeping only the cheapest free items prices in the array
    $free_item_prices = array_slice($items_prices, 0, $free_item_count);

    // summing prices for this free items
    foreach( $free_item_prices as $key => $item_price )
        $discount -= $item_price;

    if( $discount != 0 ){
        // The discount
        $label = '"'.reset($matches).'" '.__("discount");
        $wc_cart->add_fee( $label, number_format( $discount, 2 ), true, 'standard' );
        # Note: Last argument in add_fee() method is related to applying the tax or not to the discount (true or false)
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works. You will get something like:

[image]

> A coupon code (here **`2for1wow`**) need to be created with a zero price discount. When the coupon is applied to cart, a negative fee (a discount) is enabled and will free one item on two.

---

Similar answer: [WooCommerce discount: buy one get one 50% off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46264431/woocommerce-discount-buy-one-get-one-50-off/46265522#46265522)

Comment: Thank you LoicTheAztec!

But it's not working :) I've upgraded to the latest versions of WP and Woo, thinking it was maybe the problem, to no avail.

The same thing happens: nothing is calculated. You can see it in action here (even though it's in French):

https://boutique.maison4tiers.com/

You just have to add 2 DVD's at least to test it. DVD's are marked as such. Not sure why all products are labeled in red since the upgrade though.

p.s.: How do we add end of line to comments in here?

Comment: Hi Loic, about your note that I don't need a coupon code: in this case yes, because I want only clients with the coupon code to benefit from this promo.

Comment: this is what I get when reaching your page -->

https://www.screencast.com/t/Otechua5B

Comment: same for me, nothing applies. it should work without manually creating a coupon, correct?