# WooCommerce promotional discount: Buy 10 Get 1 Free

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, discount

I'm trying to set up a specific discount for three variable products (464, 465 and 466). If a customer buys ten products they get one for free.

Based on [WooCommerce discount: buy one get one 50% off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46264431/woocommerce-discount-buy-one-get-one-50-off/46265522#46265522) answer code, I've come up with the following code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_custom_discount_11th_at_100', 10, 1 );
function add_custom_discount_11th_at_100( $wc_cart ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;
    $discount = 0;
    $items_prices = array();

    // Set HERE your targeted variable product ID
    $targeted_product_id = 464;

    foreach ( $wc_cart->get_cart() as $key => $cart_item ) {
        if( $cart_item['product_id'] == $targeted_product_id ){
            $qty = intval( $cart_item['quantity'] );
            for( $i = 0; $i < $qty; $i++ )
                $items_prices[] = floatval( $cart_item['data']->get_price());
        }
    }
    $count_items_prices = count($items_prices);
    if( $count_items_prices > 10 ) foreach( $items_prices as $key => $price )
        if( $key % 11 == 1 ) $discount -= number_format($price / 1, 11 );

    if( $discount != 0 ){
        // Displaying a custom notice (optional)
        wc_clear_notices();
        wc_add_notice( __("Buy 10 Get 1 Free"), 'notice');

        // The discount
        $wc_cart->add_fee( 'Buy 10 Get 1 Free', $discount, true  );
        # Note: Last argument in add_fee() method is related to applying the tax or not to the discount (true or false)
    }
}
```

But it only works for one product ID. How do I expand it to work for three product Ids?

Comment: First when you are using an existing answer code to make your own code, please add the link in your question… What is the problem in your code and what is the question?

Comment: I adjusted a snippet I found online to achieve my goal. But it only works for one product ID. How do I expand it to work for three? I tried using array, but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work for multiple products you could use `in_array()` php function as follow:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'buy_ten_get_one_free', 10, 1 );
function buy_ten_get_one_free( $cart ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    // Set HERE your targeted variable products IDs
    $targeted_product_ids = array( 464, 465, 466 );

    $each_n_items = 10; // Number of items required to get a free one
    $discount = 0; // Initializing
    $items_prices = array(); // Initializing 

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $targeted_product_ids ) ) {
            $qty = intval( $cart_item['quantity'] );

            for ( $i = 0; $i < $qty; $i++ ) {
                $items_prices[] = floatval( $cart_item['data']->get_price() );
            }
        }
    }
    $count_items_prices = count($items_prices);

    if ( $count_items_prices > $each_n_items ) {
        foreach ( $items_prices as $key => $price ) {
            if ( $key % ($each_n_items + 1) == 1 ) {
                $discount += number_format($price, 2 );
            }
        }
    }

    if ( $discount > 0 ) {
        // Displaying a custom notice (optional)
        wc_clear_notices();
        wc_add_notice( __("Buy 10 Get 1 Free"), 'notice');

        // The discount
        $cart->add_fee( __("Buy 10 Get 1 Free"), -$discount, true  );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme), tested and works.