# Every tenth product a free gift in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, free, gift

Using [WooCommerce promotional discount: Buy 10 Get 1 Free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63873552/woocommerce-promotional-discount-buy-10-get-1-free/65904811#65904811) answer, is exactly what I was looking for. Except I need this to work for every tenth added product. So, when someone puts in a total of 10 products from $targeted_product_ids, every tenth added product should give a free gift. For example; When someone orders 10 products = 1 free gift. When someone orders 20 products = 2 free gifts. When someone orders 30 products = 3 free gifts etc. Just can't seem to adapt the code and get it to work.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the code enter the modulo part?

```
if ( ( $key + 1 ) % $each_n_items == 0 )
```

Should bring up every 10th item as true. ([docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php))

Comment: Good to hear. Good luck.

Comment: How can this be modified to accomodate a dynamic quantity requirement? Like for every nth product (can be 10, 50, or any $number specified), give a gift? Thanks