# 100% discount for every 3rd item (specific products) in the cart in Woocommerce + free shipping problem

Tags: woocommerce, checkout, shipping-method

Based on [WooCommerce promotional discount: Buy 10 Get 1 Free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63873552/woocommerce-promotional-discount-buy-10-get-1-free/63882735#63882735) answer code:

1. I have modified the code for my needs (down bellow). Buy 2 get 3. When you put 3 of the specifed products in cart (in any variation, order), it deducts 9,80€ (price of a product - all three are 9,80€). Everything works fine till 9 products. When i reach 9 products it should deduct 29,40€ (three products) but it stays on 19,80€ (two products). The 29,40€ deduction happens on the 10th product?
2. Another problem is on the checkout page. Let's say if we put 7 products in the cart. The total is 68,60€ with deduction of 19,60€ (which is correct). But now a problem appears: the total after deduction is 49,00€ (which is correct) but the system gives the buyer free shipping, but that's not correct since the free shipping in the woocommerce settings is set to 60€! For free shipping it pulls the amount before the deductions.

Hope i made it clear enough, i can explain it more if needed.

I would appreciate any help.

```html
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'buy_three_get_one_free', 10, 1 );
function buy_three_get_one_free( $cart ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    // Set HERE your targeted variable products IDs
    $targeted_product_ids = array( 5745, 5741, 5734 );

    $each_n_items = 3; // Number of items required to get a free one
    $discount = 0; // Initializing
    $items_prices = array(); // Initializing 

    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $targeted_product_ids ) ) {
            $qty = intval( $cart_item['quantity'] );

            for ( $i = 0; $i < $qty; $i++ ) {
                $items_prices[] = floatval( $cart_item['data']->get_price() );
            }
        }
    }
    $count_items_prices = count($items_prices);

    if ( $count_items_prices >= $each_n_items ) {
        foreach ( $items_prices as $key => $price ) {
            if ( $key % ($each_n_items + 1) == 1 ) {
                $discount += number_format($price, 2 );
            }
        }
    }

    if ( $discount > 0 ) {
        // Displaying a custom notice (optional)
        wc_clear_notices();
        wc_add_notice( __("On every 3 products we give you 1"), 'notice');

        // The discount
        $cart->add_fee( __("Your discount (special offer)"), -$discount, true  );
    }
}
```

Comment: To resolve issue in point number one, this line of code "if ( $key % ($each_n_items + 1) == 1 )" should be changed to this line of code "if ( $key % ($each_n_items) == ($each_n_items-1) )", it can be checked, if it works.

Comment: Thank you, that resolved point number one. Point number 2 is still a mystery.

Comment: Regarding point number two, this is because, shipping gets calculated before the hook "woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees", which is used in this code. Regarding shipping rates, the hook "woocommerce_package_rates" can be checked. The other way to implement discount functionality can be coupon discount functionality.

Comment: Replacing the hook (with rates) hangs the product being added to cart (add to cart button spins endlessly). Our marketing is already out so i can't change it to coupons. I did thought about it, but this seemed more elegant.

Comment: The hook "woocommerce_package_rates" should be used, in addition to hook "woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees", to set shipping method.

Comment: Is your issue resolved, using solution provided below?

Comment: I just checked. One product is 9,80€. If i set quantity in the cart to 7,8 or 9 it gives me a notice "Shipping is not available. Please make sure your address is entered correctly or contact us if you need help." 

It works fine to/including 6 products (i calculates discount + shipping fee) and than again above/including 10 products (if gives free shipping - also good).

Comment: The code provided in solution below works, according to requirements, with following shipping methods in admin panel: 1) flat rate shipping method 2) free shipping method with minimum order amount of 60. What are shipping methods, in admin panel, at your end?

Comment: Is there some custom code, or some plugin, to hide other shipping methods, if free shipping method is applicable in woocommerce cart? By default, all shipping methods, applicable in woocommerce cart, are displayed in cart details. In code, provided in solution below, if required condition is true, the free shipping method should not be displayed in cart details, but other applicable shipping methods should be displayed.

Comment: If there is some custom code, or some plugin, to hide other shipping methods, if free shipping method is applicable in woocommerce cart, then it can be checked, if the code provided in solution below, works at your end, when priority of hook 'woocommerce_package_rates' is changed, by replacing this line of code: "add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_woocommerce_package_rates', 100, 2 );" with this line of code: "add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_woocommerce_package_rates', 1, 2 );". It can be checked, if it works at your end.

Comment: Yes. I have a code that hides all shipping methods in free is avaliable:
https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-hide-shipping-options-free-shipping-available/ -> Unset ALL Shipping Rates

I have modified the code as you suggested. The problem "shipping is not avaliable went away. If i add 8 products to the cart the total is 63,70€ (8x9,80€ = 78,4€) with 19,60€ discount applied again the same with 9 products. It should give free shipping since the total is above 60€ but it does that from 10 products in the cart above.

Comment: Please provide details of shipping methods in admin panel. Please provide custom code, regarding hiding shipping methods, at your end. Then, I will check it, at my end.

Comment: Shipping methods: State post delivery: 4,9€, Personal collection, Free shipping: above 60€.

Comment: Code: add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'bbloomer_unset_shipping_when_free_is_available_all_zones', 10, 2 );
   
function bbloomer_unset_shipping_when_free_is_available_all_zones( $rates, $package ) {
      
$all_free_rates = array();
     
foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
      if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
         $all_free_rates[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
         break;
      }
}
     
if ( empty( $all_free_rates )) {
        return $rates;
} else {
        return $all_free_rates;
} 
 
}

Comment: According to requirements, with product price 9,80€, here are some cart calculations: 1) 8 products, (9,80€ * 8) - (9,80€ * 2) = 58,8€, 2) 9 products, (9,80€ * 9) - (9,80€ * 3)= 58,8€, so total is less than 60€, which is minimum amount for free shipping method. So, the code seems to be working correctly. Is this calculation not correct?

Comment: Is your issue resolved, using solution provided below?

Comment: Yes. The solution provided worked - thank you for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

According to provided code, to resolve issues, mentioned in point number one and point number two, this code can be used.

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'buy_three_get_one_free', 10, 1 );
function buy_three_get_one_free( $cart ){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    $targeted_product_ids = array( 5745, 5741, 5734 );

    $each_n_items = 3;
    $discount = 0;
    $items_prices = array();
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $targeted_product_ids ) ) {
            $qty = intval( $cart_item['quantity'] );

            for ( $i = 0; $i < $qty; $i++ ) {
                $items_prices[] = floatval( $cart_item['data']->get_price() );
            }
        }
    }
    $count_items_prices = count($items_prices);

    if ( $count_items_prices >= $each_n_items ) {
        foreach ( $items_prices as $key => $price ) {
            if ( $key % ($each_n_items) == ($each_n_items-1) ) {
                $discount += number_format($price, 2 );
            }
        }
    }

    if ( $discount > 0 ) {
        wc_clear_notices();
        wc_add_notice( __("On every 3 products we give you 1"), 'notice');

        $cart->add_fee( __("Your discount (special offer)"), -$discount, true  );
    }
}

function custom_woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    $targeted_product_ids = array( 5745, 5741, 5734 );

    $each_n_items = 3;
    $discount = 0;
    $items_prices = array();

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $targeted_product_ids ) ) {
            $qty = intval( $cart_item['quantity'] );

            for ( $i = 0; $i < $qty; $i++ ) {
                $items_prices[] = floatval( $cart_item['data']->get_price() );
            }
        }
    }
    $count_items_prices = count($items_prices);

    if ( $count_items_prices >= $each_n_items ) {
        foreach ( $items_prices as $key => $price ) {
            if ( $key % ($each_n_items) == ($each_n_items-1) ) {
                $discount += number_format($price, 2 );
            }
        }
    }

    if ( $discount > 0 ) {
        $free_shipping_minimum_amount = 0;
        $shipping_zone = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zone_matching_package( $package );
        $shipping_methods = $shipping_zone->get_shipping_methods( true );
        foreach ( $shipping_methods as $method ) {
            if ( $method->id == 'free_shipping' ) {
                $free_shipping_minimum_amount = $method->min_amount;
                break;
            }
        }
        if( WC()->cart->subtotal - $discount < $free_shipping_minimum_amount ) {
            foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
                if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
                    unset($rates[ $rate_id ]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_woocommerce_package_rates', 100, 2 );
```

According to point number one, the discount should be applied, when quantity of discount eligible product in cart is increased by three. So, it will provide 100% discount for every third item for discount eligible products in the cart. To resolve this issue, this line of code

```
if ( $key % ($each_n_items + 1) == 1 )
```

is changed to this line of code

```
if ( $key % ($each_n_items) == ($each_n_items-1) )
```

According to point number two, if cart total amount, after discount, is less than minimum amount for "free shipping" method, then "free shipping" method should be disabled. To resolve this issue, the hook "woocommerce_package_rates" is used.